# Paramiko not executing command or shell - Python

Tags: python, ssh

I'm using the [Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) library to run a `ssh` command between two servers.
My `"Master"` server is a `Fedora 18` box, and my `"Slave"` is a `Windows 7` machine. In other to run a `ssh` server in the `Windows 7` machine, I installed [FreeSSHd](http://www.freesshd.com/).After configuring `freesshd` I can `ssh` from the Fedora 18 machine into the Windows machine and execute a command like `dir`.
However, When I try doing so using `Paramiko`, I'm not having the same luck:

```
import paramiko
import os
import errno

"""
written by Philippe Ribeiro

class Connection
stabilishes the ssh connection between two servers
allowing the executing of commands remotely
"""
class Connection:

    def __init__( self, hostname, username, password):
        """Create a ssh client using the paramiko library
        """
        self.host = hostname
        self.user = username
        self.password = password
        self.port = 23
        self.sshclient = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

        try:        
            self.sshclient.load_system_host_keys()
            self.sshclient.set_missing_host_key_policy( paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )

            self.sshclient.connect( hostname=self.host, port=self.port, 
                    username=self.username, password=self.password )

            self.sftpclient = self.sshclient.open_sftp()

        except SSHException, e:
            print e

        except AuthenticationException, e:
            print e

        except BadHostKeyException, e:
            print e

    def close(self):
        """Closes a client using the Connection class' API
        """
        self.sshclient.close()
        return

    def remove_directory(self, path):
        """Remove remote directory that may contain files
        It does not support directories that contain subdiretories
        """
        if self.exists(path):
            for filename in self.sftpclient.listdir(path):
                filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
                self.sfptclient.remove(filepath)
            self.sftpclient.rmdir(path)

        return

    def exists(self, path):
        """Return True if the remote path exists
        """
        try:
            self.sfptclient.stat(path)

        except IOError, e:
            if e.errno == errno.ENOENT:
                return False
                raise
            else:
                return True

    def put_directory(self, localdir, remotedir):
        """Put a directory of files on the remote server
        Create the remote directory if it does not exist
        Does not support directories that contain subdirectories
        Return the number of files transferred
        """
        if not self.exists(remotedir):
             self.sftp.client.mkdir(remotedir)
        count = 0
        for filename in os.listdir(localdir):
             self.sftpclient.put(
                  os.path.join(localdir, filename),
                  os.path.join(remotedir, filename)
             )
             count += 1
        return count

"""
Just for testing purposes
try to connect to a Windows machine from a Unix one
so it can execute commands remotely
"""
cmd  = ["cd ..", "dir" ]
client = Connection("hostname", "username", "password")

try:
    for c in cmd:
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.sshclient.exec_command(c)
            print stdout.readlines()

except SSHException, e:
    print e

client.close()
```

but when I execute:

```
python client.py
```

I get:

```
['Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.\r\n']
['Unable to execute command or shell on remote system: Failed to Execute process.\r\n']
```

Could someone please give me a clue why isn't working? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `cmd  = ["cd ..", "dir" ]` with `cmd  = ['cmd.exe /c "cd C:\ && dir"' ]`

Comment: good example @Yevgen. Just clarification - if your current directory is on drive with letter D, for example, and you want cd to C:\, so `cmd = ['cmd.exe /c "c: && dir"']`. Without cd and backslash